# Sending notifications between instances of the page in the same browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is it possible to create a channel for sending messages between two instances of the page (or two different pages) in same domain but in two different tabs/windows (same machine) using new HTML5 APIs?

For instance I have one page with JavaScript single page app and when I get click logout in one window or login I get login/logout on other window.

Is it possible to do this without websockets? Maybe WebRTC. How should I implement something like this?

Comment: believe you'll need websockets. Browsers like Chrome run tabs in separate processes so the barriers between two tabs talking are quite significant.

Comment: Yes. You can use `localStorage` and the `onstorage` event to establish basic communication between same-domain tabs in your browser.

Comment: If you just want to get informed in other Tabs I'd aim for HTML5's `postMessage`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

However, a login / logout process requires action on your server anyways, so for that purpose it probably comes in very natural to use websockets and react on servers push notification.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol your solution is great, I've create quick POC and it's working, I've added an answer with the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @NiettheDarkAbsol suggets you can use localstorage to send messages in same browser. here is short POC code (in vanila JS)

```js
window.onload = function() {
    window.addEventListener('storage', storageEventHandler, false);

    function storageEventHandler(e) {
        console.log(localStorage.getItem(e.key));
    }
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

    document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function() {
        localStorage.setItem('name', input.value);
    };
};
```

with html

```html
<input/>
<button>notif</button>
```

the only limitation is that message need to be different then the previus one. You can fix it if you send id of the request (like in JSON-RPC).

**UPDATE**: here is simple library that I've just made just for that: https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js

Comment: Wait, you actually made it work? o_O I only knew about this in theory, when I tried it myself it was a horrendous failure. Kudos to you for getting it, then!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I've just created simple library for that.